# How to make the Parsec chainl1 function follow operator precedence rules

Tags: haskell, parsec, combinators

I'm programming a standard math notation -> [DC](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html) POSIX-compliant format converter. It takes the input string, parses it into an intermediary data type and then turns it into the output string by `show`ing it.

This is the Data type used. I have no problems with the Data type -> Output String conversion, it works flawlessly:

```
data Expression = Expression :+ Expression
                | Expression :- Expression
                | Expression :* Expression
                | Expression :/ Expression
                | Expression :^ Expression
                | Cons String

infixr 0 :+
infixr 0 :-
infixr 1 :*
infixr 1 :/
infixr 2 :^

instance Show Expression where
  show (x :+ y) = unwords [show x, show y, "+"]
  show (x :- y) = unwords [show x, show y, "-"] 
  show (x :* y) = unwords [show x, show y, "*"]
  show (x :/ y) = unwords [show x, show y, "/"]
  show (x :^ y) = unwords [show x, show y, "^"]
  show (Cons y) = y
```

The Parsec parser part, however, refuses to comply with the defined operator precedency rules. Clearly because of the way `chainl1` is used in the `subexpression` parser definition:

```
expression :: Parser Expression
expression = do
  spaces
  x <- subexpression
  spaces >> eof >> return x

subexpression :: Parser Expression
subexpression = (
    (bracketed subexpression) <|>
    constant
  ) `chainl1` (
    try addition              <|>
    try substraction          <|>
    try multiplication        <|>
    try division              <|>
    try exponentiation
  )

addition       = operator '+' (:+)
substraction   = operator '-' (:-)
multiplication = operator '*' (:*)
division       = operator '/' (:/)
exponentiation = operator '^' (:^)

operator :: Char -> (a -> a -> a) -> Parser (a -> a -> a)
operator c op = do
  spaces >> char c >> spaces
  return op

bracketed :: Parser a -> Parser a
bracketed parser = do
  char '('
  x <- parser
  char ')'
  return x

constant :: Parser Expression
constant = do
  parity <- optionMaybe $ oneOf "-+"
  constant <- many1 (digit <|> char '.')
  return (if parity == Just '-'
    then (Cons $ '_':constant)
    else  Cons       constant)
```

Is there a way of making the parser take into account the operator precedence rules without having to rewrite the entirety of my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you don't need to rewrite your *entire* code, but since your `subexpression` parser doesn't take precedence into account at all, you have to rewrite that - substantially.

One possibility is to build it from parsers for subexpressions with top-level operators with the same precedence,

```
atom :: Parser Expression
atom = bracketed subexpression <|> constant

-- highest precedence operator is exponentiation, usually that's
-- right-associative, hence I use chainr1 here
powers :: Parser Expression
powers = atom `chainr1` try exponentiation

-- a multiplicative expression is a product or quotient of powers,
-- left-associative
multis :: Parser Expression
multis = powers `chainl1` (try multiplication <|> try division)

-- a subexpression is a sum (or difference) of multiplicative expressions
subexpression :: Parser Expression
subexpression = multis `chainl1` (try addition <|> try substraction)
```

Another option is to let the precedence and associativities be taken care of by the library and use [`Text.Parsec.Expr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Expr.html), namely [`buildExpressionParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Expr.html#v%3abuildExpressionParser):

```
table = [ [binary "^" (:^) AssocRight]
        , [binary "*" (:*) AssocLeft, binary "/" (:/) AssocLeft]
        , [binary "+" (:+) AssocLeft, binary "-" (:-) AssocLeft]
        ]

binary  name fun assoc = Infix (do{ string name; spaces; return fun }) assoc

subexpression = buildExpressionParser table atom
```

(which requires that `bracketed parser` and `constant` consume the spaces after the used tokens).

Comment: Thank you. This parser encapsulation was exactly what I needed. So far I've only worked with Regular Expressions, so the context-sensitive capabilities of Parsec and the like still make my head spin a little.

Comment: You'll have to relearn a bit then, but writing parsers is much easier than regular expressions for even mildly complicated things once you got your feet wet.